# Can't open/read file error / 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'

Tags: python, file

I'm trying to run my Python code to open file in JPG extension (csv file consists only file name, without extension). Here's a part of it:

```
//config file
BASE_PATH = "dataset"
IMAGES_PATH = os.path.sep.join([BASE_PATH, "images"])
ANNOTS_PATH = os.path.sep.join([BASE_PATH, "bboxes.csv"])

//main file
rows = open(config.ANNOTS_PATH).read().strip().split("\n")
data = []
targets = []
filenames = []

for row in rows: 
    row = row.split(' ')
    (filename, startX, startY, endX, endY) = row
    suffix = ".jpg"
    imagePath = os.path.sep.join([config.IMAGES_PATH, filename+suffix])
    image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
    (h, w) = image.shape[:2]
```

But get the next error:

```
> [ WARN:0@0.049] global
> /Users/runner/work/opencv-python/opencv-python/opencv/modules/imgcodecs/src/loadsave.cpp
> (239) findDecoder imread_('dataset/images/"2007_000027.jpg'): can't
> open/read file: check file path/integrity Traceback (most recent call
> last):   File "/Users/username/Downloads/lr2_a/train.py", line 30, in
> <module>
>     (h, w) = image.shape[:2] AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

Please help me solve this problem

Comment: `//config file`: that is no valid Python syntax. Be careful with code blocks of what you include. Separate the code blocks for the two files at least.

Comment: Compare file path you see in error message with one your file manager show.

Comment: And please format tracebacks as code.

Comment: So `image` is `None`, which probably means that `cv2.imread` didn't read the file correctly (or not at all, that is, couldn't find the file).

Comment: @9769953 The program has 2 files: config.py and main.py. The first 3 lines are stored in config file, the rest - in main file. I don't understand why i get 'dataset/images/"2007_000027.jpg'? It should be 'dataset/images/2007_000027.jpg', doesn't it? The path of files is right, the 2007_000027.jpg is really stored in dataset/images/ folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that you may have a leading double quote at the beginning of the row with *2007_000027*, as it is found here: ('dataset/images/ --> " <-- 2007_000027.jpg').

Strip that quote, with:

`rows = open(config.ANNOTS_PATH).read().strip('\"').split("\n")`

Btw, check if your csv file data is formatted correctly.